# React component retrieves props just once, goes undefined when refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple movie app with moviedb. I have successfully retrieved the most popular 20 movies and put them in the app state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movieInfo: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMovies();
  }

  getMovies = async () => {
    await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=94d4ad026c5009bdaf4aecb8989dfa07')
    .then(res => this.setState({ movieInfo: res.data.results }))
  }
```

I know the array was retrieved correctly because when I look at the React components in Chrome dev tools I see what I want:

[Screen cap of App state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5euB6.png)

Then in the render part of the App I want to pass the first element in the array to a component called Movie, which will then display some info about the movie:

```
    return (
      <div>
        <Movie movie={this.state.movieInfo[0]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I know the movie component is getting this info correctly because I see the object representing the first movie in the Movie component props:

[Movie component props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuFhL.png)

My Movie function looks like this:

```
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.movie.original_title}</h1>
            <p>{props.movie.overview}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The first time I compile it this works and I see the info I want:

[Rendered App with Movie component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue5hO.png)

But incredibly, when I refresh the page I see the error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'original_title')
```

How is it possible that the App will correctly pass on the info to Movie and will display it correctly once, but as soon as I refresh the page somehow it's undefined?

Thanks in advance for the help,
JD

Comment: Rendering before the async call returns still needs to be handled; components will be rendered before the data is available.

Comment: Thanks for the response...what exactly does that mean? When I refresh does movieInfo reset to the empty array?

Comment: Sure; a refresh erases everything and starts all over--the page is reloading.

Comment: So what would I need to do so that when I reload the page it correctly retrieves the data and re-renders?

Comment: What you're doing now. The point is that the component will render *before the async call has completed* so the rendering needs to handle that, like by displaying a different component altogether, or with dummy filler data like "Loading...", etc. There are a number of ways it can be handled.

Comment: Ah so maybe add a if...then where if the data hasn't come in yet it shows a loading... message and then once the call is complete and the data comes in show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you don't get an error when you are developing and changing code. When you save your code Hot reloading only changes parts that changed.

This means that if your app loads data and populates `this.state.movieInfo` with an array from BE, and your save you code, it Hot reloads and you get new data. So, `this.state.movieInfo[0]` is always filled with data.

When you refresh your app, it just resets to an empty array as you put it there in the `constructor`.

Solution is to always check if there is that first element in array before rendering the `Movie` component:

```js
return (
  <div>
    {this.state.movieInfo[0] ? <Movie movie={this.state.movieInfo[0]} /> : null}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hehe, well sometimes you need sanity check after long hours of work. Glad i helped. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also use componentDidUpdate() with componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getMovies();
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getMovies();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it didn't work...

Comment: This won't change the underlying problem: an async call completes at an arbitrary time in the future, while the component code will just plow ahead and render before the call has completed and data has returned.

Answer (score 0):

when the page reloads init state is an empty array. you have to check the array has an item to render or not.

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.state.movieInfo && this.state.movieInfo.length>0 && (<Movie 
    movie={this.state.movieInfo[0]} />)}
    
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you, implementing logic like this solved my problem!